# Evaluate line integral in polar coordinates system with changing basis

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

Suppose I am working in the polar  coordinate $(r,\theta)$ system with unit vectors $\hat r,\hat \theta$ and wanted to evaluate the integral
$$\int_C \theta \; \mathrm d\hat\theta$$ circular path $C$ (e.g. quarter circle).

I understand that, using coordinate transformations, I could express the d$\hat \theta $ in terms of the cartesian basis which are constant.

However, how could we perform this integral *without changing coordinate systems*.

My guess would be to express $\theta$ in terms of $\hat \theta$, but I do not now how to go about that without effectively ending up in cartesian coordinates again.

Comment: What is the semicircular path?

Comment: is $\hat{\theta}$ just $\theta/|\theta|$? It seems like your integral is $\int_0^\pi \theta/|\theta| d \theta$. Is that right?

Comment: @AlfredYerger $\hat{\theta}$ is the unit vector $-\sin\theta \hat{x} + \cos\theta \hat{y}$

Comment: @AlfredYerger The unit vector is $\hat\theta = -\sin\theta \hat x + \cos\theta \hat y$.  My problem is that the only way I can think of defining it is in terms of cartesian coordinates, and I want to perform this integral in cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: Typically the way people go about this sort of thing is they parametrize the curve and then do the integral over the parametrizing interval.

Comment: @AlfredYerger, yes but that parametrization is afaik done using constant basis in cartesian coordinates. I am trying to see if there is another way, with perhaps a parametrization in polar coordinates with basis that are not constant

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$\int_C \theta \:d\hat{\theta} = \int_\alpha^\beta -\theta\:\hat{r}\:d\theta$$

Now we can use a justified integration by parts

$$= \theta \:\hat{\theta}\Bigr|_\alpha^\beta - \int_\alpha^\beta\hat{\theta}\:d\theta = \boxed{\beta\:\hat{\theta}(\beta)-\alpha\:\hat{\theta}(\alpha)-\hat{r}(\beta)+\hat{r}(\alpha)}$$